# Como paso parámetros de entrada ingresada por el usuario a una función de otro archivo php?

Tags: php

No he podido realizar esto:

> Hacer una función llamada operaciones() que realice las operaciones  aritméticas básicas (suma, resta, multiplicación y división) entre dos números, recibiendo como parámetros los dos datos sobre los que se realizará la operación y un tercer parámetro que le indique a la función la  operación a realizar. la función debe seleccionar qué operación hacer, ejecutarla y retornar el resultado.
>
> Almacenar la función en un archivo llamado biblioteca.php y úsela (llámela)  en un archivo llamado index.php (por lo tanto, el archivo biblioteca.php debe incluirse o requerirse desde dicho archivo).

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es esto:

Este es el archivo index.php

```
<head>
<title>Operaciones basicas</title>
</head>
<script>
//verifica que solo puedan entrar numeros en el formulario
var a = window.Event ? true : false;
function soloNum(evt){    
var key = a ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;    
return (key <= 13 || (key >= 48 && key <= 57));
}
</script>

<?php 
require_once 'biblioteca.php';
?>
<p>Operaciones Basicas [S:+ R:- M:* D:/]</p>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="biblioteca.php">
<input type="text" name="primero" onkeypress="return soloNum(event)" />
<input type="text" name="operador" style="width:20px;" maxlength="1"/>
<input type="text" name="segundo" onkeypress="return soloNum(event)" />
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Resultado" />

<?php
operaciones('primero','segundo','operador');
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

archivo bibliboteca.php:

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){ 

function operaciones($num1, $num2, $oper){ 

$num1=$_POST['primero'];
$num2=$_POST['segundo'];
$oper=$_POST['operador'];

if($oper=='s'){
$resul=$num1+$num2;
echo "El resultado de la suma es: " . $resul;

}
if($oper=='r'){
$resul=$num1-$num2;
echo "El resultado de la resta es: ".$resul;
}
if($oper=='m'){
$resul=$num1*$num2;
echo "El resultado de la multiplicacion es: ".$resul;
}
if($oper=='d'){
$resul=$num1/$num2;
echo "El resultado de la divison es: ".$resul;
}
}
}
?>
```

Pero no me funciona.

Comment: El require_once deberia estar también entre etiquetas de php.

Comment: @Error404 Ya lo corrige pero igual no funciona...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola @Juanzu el mejor consejo puedo darte ahora que inicias en PHP es: **¡formatea tu código siempre!** (ya te ayudará en el futuro).

Ahora, pasando a tu problema, habría que traducir tu código al español y dice más menos asi:

Sí la variable $_POST['enviar'] existe entonces crea la función operaciones que toma 3 argumentos por input, de lo contrario nada.

Mi propuesta para que tu código haga lo que quieres que haga es **¡usa la función después de crearla!**

Igual puedes usar los argumentos que le estás pasando a la función porque no sirve de nada que los declares como argumentos si los sobrescribes *dentro* de tu función. Considera el siguiente código:

index:

```
<head>
 <title>Operaciones basicas</title>
 <script>
  var a = window.Event ? true : false;
  function soloNum(evt){    
   var key = a ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;    
   return (key <= 13 || (key >= 48 && key <= 57)); 
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Operaciones Basicas [S:+ R:- M:* D:/]</p>
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="primero" onkeypress="return soloNum(event)" />
  <input type="text" name="operador" style="width:20px;" maxlength="1"/>
  <input type="text" name="segundo" onkeypress="return soloNum(event)" />
  <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Resultado" />
 </form>
<?php
 require_once 'biblioteca.php';
?>
</body>
```

biblioteca.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
 function operaciones($num1, $num2, $oper){ 
  if($oper=='s'){
   $resul=$num1+$num2;
   echo "El resultado de la suma es: " . $resul;
  }elseif($oper=='r'){
   $resul=$num1-$num2;
   echo "El resultado de la resta es: ".$resul;
  } elseif($oper=='m'){
   $resul=$num1*$num2;
   echo "El resultado de la multiplicacion es: ".$resul;
  } elseif($oper=='d'){
   $resul=$num1/$num2;
   echo "El resultado de la divison es: ".$resul;
  }
 }
 operaciones($_POST['primero'], $_POST['segundo'],$_POST['operador'] );
}
```

Espero que esto ayude.

Comment: Hola, pues o tomare como consejo. pero ahora me salen muchos errores:    Notice: Undefined variable: oper in C:\xampp\htdocs\sena\resultado.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: oper in C:\xampp\htdocs\sena\resultado.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined variable: oper in C:\xampp\htdocs\sena\resultado.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined variable: oper in C:\xampp\htdocs\sena\resultado.php on line 19                                                    Fatal error: Call to undefined function operaciones() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sena\oper.php on line 31

Comment: Intenta este código, me parece que había malintrpretado tu necesidad al principio.

Comment: Hola, la verdad no veo el código que me mencionqw

Comment: Perdona, tienes que hacer el POST al mismo archivo porque estás incluyendo biblioteca.php la propiedad `action` de tu `form` debe quedar en blanco.

Comment: No me había fijado en tu código el action, problema resulto Gracias!!